# i am redirected to another site on successful login

Tags: wordpress

i recently took over a wordpress site that is a sub dormain of an eCommerce site.

i have installed it on my local wamp and i now wish to log into the wordpress dashboard.

the problem is that the once i log in to wordpress it redirects me back to the old site.

i am now trying to work out where the redirect functionality might be located.

i have already changed the base url address in the table `wp_options`.

within this table i changed both the **siteurl** and the  **home**.

i also tried changing the wp-config.php file with the new url:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourdomain.com');
```

i would appreciate any ideas on where the redirect functionality might be located.

Comment: Have you checked the .htaccess file for anything funky? Also, could you possibly add a list of plugins? it may be a caching issue or maybe a security plugin such as Wordfence which keeps the URL in a file.

Comment: there can also be a filter in the functions.php in your theme

Comment: You can use `https://wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls` plugin for update all the urls.

Comment: @ShahajiDeshmukh hi. but would this work for local host. at the moment i am working on my loca host files, trying to fix it first before going LIVE

Comment: Yes. @Paul Kendal It is working for both localhost and live server.